# SQL if pivot table is empty = no result

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

I made this simple database on mysql and with data in my "Work" pivot table, I get the expected results with :

```
SELECT emp_name, dept_name
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN Work w ON e.emp_id=w.emp_id
INNER JOIN Department d ON w.dept_id=d.dept_id;
+----------+-----------+
| emp_name | dept_name |
+----------+-----------+
| James    | Sales     |
| Jack     | Marketing |
| James    | Finance   |
| Tom      | Marketing |
+----------+-----------+
```

But now, if my pivot table is empty, I get NO RESULT as I would expect at least my emp_name list :

```
+----------+
| emp_name |
+----------+
| James    |
| Jack     | 
| Henry    |
| Tom      | 
+----------+
```

==> What should be the query for that ???
Thanks for help !

```
+--------+----------+--------+ Employee table
| emp_id | emp_name | salary |
+--------+----------+--------+
| 1      | James    |   2000 |
| 2      | Jack     |   4000 |
| 3      | Henry    |   6000 |
| 4      | Tom      |   8000 |
+--------+----------+--------+

+-------+-----------+ Department table
|dept_id| dept_name |
+-------+-----------+
| 1     | Sales     |
| 2     | Marketing |
| 3     | Finance   |
+-------+-----------+

+--------+---------+ Work table
| emp_id | dept_id |
+--------+---------+
|      1 |       1 |
|      2 |       2 |
|      1 |       3 |
|      4 |       2 |
+--------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a "left outer join":

```
SELECT emp_name, dept_name
FROM Employee e
LEFT JOIN Work w ON e.emp_id=w.emp_id
LEFT JOIN Department d ON w.dept_id=d.dept_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want `left join`:

```
SELECT emp_name, dept_name
FROM Employee e LEFT JOIN
     Work w
     ON e.emp_id = w.emp_id LEFT JOIN
     Department d
     ON w.dept_id = d.dept_id;
```

Note that this still returns two columns, but the second column is `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer with a different syntax. I'll stick on the first answer for a PHP dev. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In some situations, you need to fabricate a table for the columns.

I wanted a table with 24 columns, one per hour.  In the output, I would put counts for actions grouped by day + hour.  When there was no action in an hour, I wanted blank, not zero.  (Blank stands out more than "0".)

To achieve that, I built a table with just 0..23.

```
SELECT ...
    FROM seq_0_to_23 AS hours
    LEFT JOIN the_data ON ...
```